# CSS applied to nested li issue

Tags: javascript, css

I have ul list in which there are some li which having nested li as well.

I have added js in which onclick of li, its change bgcolor of li,but issue is its spreading to nested li as well.

my code is :

```
 <  ul >
    < li >

       < a > first </ a>

    /%nested ul starts here%/
     <li> 
        Nested Word
     </li>
   </li>
</ul>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('li').click(function(e){


   $(this).addClass("active1");
   $(this).find('a').addClass("acolor");

  });
```

CSS

```
 .acolor
 {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
 }

.active1
{
  background-color:#536574 !important;

}
```

Issues is when I am applying bg color to main div, its appying to near by padding of nesed li as well, which I dont need. I need just bg color to apply first text and not anywhere to its children.

-> I cant change HTML structure as its already code coming from Drupal widget.

Is there any solution ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Why is it not possible to change the html or the drupal widget' html? (no xp with drupal tho)

Answer (score 0):

The `$('li')` jQuery statement selects *every* `<li>` in your DOM, including the ones you don't want to select. If you just want to change the background color of your text elements (`<a>` tags) you could rewrite the statement like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   $(this).addClass("active1");
   $(this).find('a').addClass("acolor");
});
```

Or if you wanted to selecxt just the first `<li>` inside your `<ul>`, select them like this:

```
$('ul li:first-child').click(function(e){
   $(this).addClass("active1");
   $(this).find('a').addClass("acolor");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to select the a tag directly under the clicked li just use the child selector ">" which would result in the following javascript:

```
$('li').click(function(e){
   $(this).addClass("active1");
   $(this).find('> a').addClass("acolor");
});
```